# EF Core one-to-many with IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to create a one-to-many relationship between a model based on a table (`Driver`) and a model based on a SQL query (`DriverSchedule`).

I'm having difficulty getting this architecture to function.

`Driver` model:

```
[Table("Drivers")]
public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    [Column("DriverKey")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<DriverSchedule> DriverSchedules { get; set; }
}
```

`DriverSchedule` model:

```
public class DriverSchedule
{
    public int DriverID { get; set; }  // foreign key
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

`VendorDbContext` context:

```
public class VendorDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DriverSchedule>().HasKey(table => new { table.DriverID, table.Date });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().HasMany(d => d.DriverSchedules).WithOne(s => s.Driver);
        ...
        modelBuilder.Query<DriverSchedule>();
    }

    public IQueryable<DriverSchedule> DriverSchedules(DateTime startingDate, DateTime endingDate) =>
        Query<DriverSchedule>().FromSql("<SQL>");
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Driver>
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@(item.Name)</td>
        <td>@(item.ID)</td>
        <td><ul>
            foreach (var driverSchedule in item.DriverSchedules)
            {
                <li>@(driverSchedule.ToString("MM/dd/yy") - @(driverSchedule.IsScheduled)</li>
            }
        </ul></td>
    </tr>
}
...
```

My LINQ query:

```
var model = await (
    from driver in _context.Drivers
    join schedule in _context.DriverSchedules(startDate.Date, endDate.Date) on driver.ID equals schedule.DriverID
    orderby driver.LastName, driver.FirstName
    select driver
).Include(x => x.DriverSchedules)
.ToListAsync();
```

When I run the code, this line:

```
modelBuilder.Query<DriverSchedule>();
```

generates an error:

> The query type 'DriverSchedule' cannot be added to the model because
>   an entity type with the same name already exists.

** edit 0 **

This posting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt847184.aspx suggests that I need to

Remove the navigation property from `Driver`:

```
//public virtual ICollection<DriverSchedule> DriverSchedules { get; set; }
```

Remove the navigation property from `DriverSchedule`:

```
//public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
```

Remove the relationship definitions from `OnModelCreating`:

```
// modelBuilder.Entity<DriverSchedule>().HasKey(table => new { table.DriverID, table.Date });
// modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().HasMany(d => d.DriverSchedules).WithOne(s => s.Driver);
```

Change the query interface:

```
IQueryable<DriverSchedule> DriverSchedules(DateTime startingDate, DateTime endingDate) =>
        Query<DriverSchedule>() ...
```

Define a relationship between the query and the entity:

```
modelBuilder.Query<DriverSchedule>().HasOne<Driver>().WithMany();
```

Then re-write the query:

```
model = await _context.DriverSchedules(startDate.Date, endDate.Date)
           .Include("Driver")
           .ToListAsync();
```

Which fails with this error:

> The property 'Driver' is not a navigation property of entity type
>   'DriverSchedule'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a
>   '.' separated list of navigation property names.

** /edit 0 **

** edit 1 **

```
SELECT  m.DriverID, c.Date
        ,CAST( CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN c.date <> CAST(m.StartTime AS DATE) THEN NULL ELSE m.MovementID end)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) IsScheduled
FROM    dbo.Calendar c
CROSS APPLY vMovements m
WHERE  1 = 1
AND   c.date BETWEEN {startingDate} AND {endingDate}
AND   m.DriverID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.date, m.DriverID
```

** /edit 1 **

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you already have a entity called *DriverSchedule*

problem here:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DriverSchedule>();
modelBuilder.Query<DriverSchedule>(); // wrong.
```

create another model in order to get and map data results in DriverSchedules method. So:

```
public class Driversched
{
    public int DriverID { get; set; }  // foreign key
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
modelBuilder.Query<Driversched>();
```

And finally:

```
 public IQueryable<Driversched> DriverSchedules(DateTime startingDate, DateTime endingDate) =>
        Query<DriverSchedule>().FromSql("<SQL>");
```

advice, Never use an entity class as a model.

Comment: I don't see how the `IQueryable<Driversched>` model is connected to the `Driver`.  When I enumerate the `driver.DriverSchedules` how will it know if it is referencing `ICollection<DriverSchedule> ` or `IQueryable<Driversched>`?

Comment: in order to see better your problem, can you share your  SQL query?